# Upgrading from PHP 5.3 to 5.6.26

Tags: visual-studio, wamp, php-5.6

I need to upgrade my version of PHP from 5.3 to 5.6.26.

I went over this tutorial to upgrade PHP but after following the steps my WampServer is stuck @ orange never goes green.
https://john-dugan.com/upgrade-php-wamp/

So, I am looking for some advice on the steps I need to take before moving forward.

I believe I may need to upgrade my version of Visual Studio to V11 for PHP 5.6.26 to work.

Will I need to update my version of WampServer for this to work also? 
I hope not. I know its an old version, but the tutorials I have seen to do this correctly, making sure all current DB's are backed up and and MySQL folders saved, seems extensive and not understanding all the steps could be error prone for me.
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606

Windows 10

WampServer - 2.2

PHP - 5.6.26 - Thread Safe version

Apache - 2.2.21

MySQL - 5.5.20

Visual Studio - MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)

Comment: The problem here is that if you want to upgrade PHP from 5.3 to 5.6 you will also have to upgrade your Apache from 2.2 to 2.4 as PHP5.6 will not run in Apache 2.2 So if you are struggling with upgrading PHP then you are going to struggle with upgrading Apache.

Comment: As I wrote the Document you link to on the WAMPServer forum, I can be of assistance if you like. Post a question of the forum, and if I cannot help via the question, maybe I can offer you a TeamViewer session, and we can do the upgrade together, so to speak

Comment: It doesn't have to be php 5.6. For the project I am working on I need to work with PHP 5.5. Does the lower version make this any easier, quicker